# Spark Streaming MYsql

Tags: mysql, spark-streaming

I want to fetch data rows that is being inserted into external mysql database
after every 2 minutes.I want to do this thing with Spark Streaming.

But I got this error after program run for one time.So its gives me the data for the first time but after that I got the following error and program terminated

Error I got is

```
16/08/02 11:15:44 INFO JdbcRDD: closed connection
16/08/02 11:15:44 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0). 620 bytes result sent to driver
16/08/02 11:15:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 451 ms on localhost (1/1)
16/08/02 11:15:44 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/08/02 11:15:44 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (foreach at databaseread.scala:33) finished in 0.458 s
16/08/02 11:15:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: foreach at databaseread.scala:33, took 0.664559 s
16/08/02 11:15:44 ERROR StreamingContext: Error starting the context, marking it as stopped
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.validate(DStreamGraph.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.validate(StreamingContext.scala:543)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.liftedTree1$1(StreamingContext.scala:595)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.start(StreamingContext.scala:594)
    at org.test.spark.databaseread$.main(databaseread.scala:41)
    at org.test.spark.databaseread.main(databaseread.scala)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
```

I am posting my code over here.Please help me

```
package org.test.spark

import org.xml.sax.helpers.NewInstance
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.JdbcRDD
import java.sql.DriverManager
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds

object databaseread {   
         def main(args:Array[String])
         {
              val url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname"
              val uname="root"
              val pwd="root"
              var i=0
              val driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              val conf=new SparkConf().setAppName("DBget").setMaster("local")
              val sc=new SparkContext(conf)
              val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(60))

         val RDD=new JdbcRDD(sc,()=>DriverManager.getConnection(url,uname,pwd),
            "select * from crimeweathercoords where ?  
                =?",1,1,1,r=>r.getString("Borough")+","+r.getString("Month"))



        ssc.checkpoint(".")


        ssc.start()
        ssc.awaitTermination()


      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

consider using mysql binlog  to kafka, then  consume by KafkaUtils.createStream, or using flinksql  cdc or  flink streaming api

Answer (score -1):

Spark streaming is not designed to read data from an RDBMS like MySQL. You could try to create your own custom receiver, but at that point it might be easier to just use the regular spark api to retrieve the data in chunks.

Comment: not necessarily true, a lot of purchase decisions that are transaction based in the financial industry uses transactional databases as the source. Don't generalize!

Comment: @karthikr there was no mysql support for spark streaming when I wrote that comment. Has anything changed?